# Switching application from SQL Auth to Windows Auth causes connection queing under stress

Tags: sql-server, performance, authentication

We're switching from using SQL auth to windows auth per microsoft best practices (https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/2028697/recommendations-and-guidelines-on-configuring-the-authentication-mode)

We've switched the majority of our systems over to no ill effect however when we switched our mobile website over we were fine for several hours up until our site got busy.

At that point connections started queuing, CPU climbs on our database server and load time on the site shoots through the roof.

Normally I would open a case with Micosoft support to troubleshoot but in this instance we're running SQL 2005 which is EoL. (Before lecturing me on SQL 2005 being end of life - we know we're in the process of building SQL 2017 servers and migrating.)

Before we migrate though we wanted to complete the migration from SQL auth to windows auth except for this problem.

Our connection strings to the server look as such:

Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=OURSERVER;Initial Catalog=OURDATABASE;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist security info=False;Trusted_Connection=Yes;

Data Source=OURSERVER;Initial Catalog=OURDATABASE;Integrated Security=SSPI;

I don't see anything all that interesting in the system, application or security logs either on the database or web server. Likewise I checked our domain controllers. I should also note that we have similar servers in test where we don't see this problem (even during load tests).

Has anyone else experienced anything like this and have any advise for things we might check from a perfmon counters standpoint or otherwise.

Comment: Check the auth_scheme column in sys.dm_exec_connections.  It will either by NTLM or Kerberos.  There are perfmon counters on the DC that relate to each.  Also, NTLM has issues at high request volumes.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in replying back. We were using NTLM but I modified our config to get Kerberos working. Sadly the issue still persists. Any other ideas?